# Read Outlook Msg File in .NET 4 to save attachment to disk

Tags: c#, .net, email

I need to read an Outlook msg file and save any attachments to file.  I'm using .NET 4 & C#.

I'm aware of [Aspose.Network for .NET](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.network-for-.net/default.aspx) - are there any free libraries that do not require Outlook to be installed on the server?